# AWS Device Farm error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK, but I have backwards compatibility

Tags: android, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

So I'm receiving the following error when device farm devices with Android 7.0 (and lower) try to install my application:

```
Failed to install com.carto.advanced.kotlin.test - 
INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: 
/data/app/vmdl777879102.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #5): 
Requires newer sdk version #25 (current version is #24)
```

While it is technically correct, I am targeting **sdk 25**, I also have **backwards compatibility** installed and this should not be a problem.

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'`

Here's the relevant section of my build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.carto.advanced.kotlin"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 4
    versionName "0.3.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "xxxx"]
}
```

It installs and runs on everything **>=18 just fine**, I've tested it on **several** devices. What's going on here?

It's worth mentioning that I'm using espresso version 2.2.2 and UIAutomator version-v18:2.0.0

```
compile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.0.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

Image from error page:

[image: Image from error page]

Image from result page:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not resolved, but answering my own question, as the question is no longer relevant – it's not related to AWS Device Farm.

By analyzing the test's .apk, I found out that Android Studio does some weird magic where it override's the tests `minSdkVersion`.

From Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html): *You can add your own manifest file if necessary, such as to specify a different value for `minSdkVersion` or register run listeners just for your tests*.

So I created a separate manifest for my test (and it does use it), but `build.gradle` still overrides `minSdkVersion` to be the `targetSdkVersion`.

Will update my answer when it's solved.

Comment: I'd say that's nothing to be solved by AWS, setting something like

<uses-sdk
      android:maxSdkVersion="26"
      android:minSdkVersion="21"
      android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>

in AndroidManifest in androidTest directory is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nikitah,

> Failed to install com.carto.advanced.kotlin.test

The package that is failing to install ends with `.test` which tells me that it's the instrumentation APK and not the actual application APK that is failing to install.

My guess is that the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your instrumentation APK has the `minSdkVersion` set to 25 (or is unset).

You can confirm using `aapt`. For example:

`⇒  aapt debug badging <your-instrumentation.apk> | grep -i sdkversion
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'24'`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cheerio, it was indeed caused by the instrumentation's manifest having minSdkVersion="23", however, the test's AndroidManifest.xml is autogenerated.

If I run the test on an android device with a lower version (e.g. 5.1), the auto-generated minSdkVersion is correct -- 18, as specified in my build.gradle. 

Now that I've added a manifest file to my test, it still overrides it to minSdkVersion="23"

That's some weird-ass Android Studio magic right here.